# How to solve "The name 'ViewData' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewdata

When I try and pass data to my view from a controller using ViewData I get the error in the title, when referencing the ViewData property in my view

I am using the Razor View engine, there are several posts around related to this, but they seem to be relevant to web forms implementations

I suspect there is an issue with how Razor is referenced: my config file has a number of warnings:

[image]

Those type references are warning : Invalid Module Qualification: Unable to resolve assembly System.Web.WebPages.Razor

The generic MVC stuff is working ok (using only Model references) but trying to access ViewData - no luck

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using `ViewData` instead of having strongly typed views and view models? As I don't see any.

Comment: No - I'm really just experimenting with MVC generally. I take your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MVC3 ViewBag has been added. It's just the dynamic wrapper around the ViewData. Now you can use something like that :

```
ViewBag.Title = "Test";
```

One of the cool benefits of using ViewBag over ViewData is we don't have to cast ViewBag.Date to DateTime, ViewBag.Post to Post, and ViewBag.Tags to a string array before using them as such. This cuts down on the noise in the view.

But as Darin said in the comment it's best to use a strongly typed views.

Errors you're getting in web.config are not related to that. However I'm not sure what's the exact cause for these errors but it seems that it doesn't affect the application run.

Comment: @Thomas Jaskula, ViewData is still supported in MVC3 for backwards compatibility though.

Comment: `ViewData` hasn't been renamed to `ViewBag`. `ViewBag` has been added in ASP.NET MVC 3. This being said, none of those two concepts should be used in a properly architected ASP.NET MVC application. Strongly typed views and view models are the correct way to proceed.

Comment: Yes it's true, it's just a dynamic wrapper around the ViewData

Comment: Thanks - using viewbag syntax instead did work, but I was under the impression that ViewBag was just a wrapper over ViewData, for readability?

Comment: @Embo, yes ViewBag is just a dynamic wrapper over ViewData.

Comment: @Darin, I agree with that. I have modified my answer.

Comment: @Thomas Jaskula, that's much better. Now at least we ensure that people that might stumble across this answer in the future don't make the mistake of ever using ViewData or ViewBag in their applications.

Comment: @Darin: You've mentioned ViewModels again. You truly are my hero! ;-)

Comment: @Dommer, of course that I will mention them. They simply are the answer to all problems that people encounter with ASP.NET MVC, so I will continue to insist on their importance.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov OK, this all being said, I'm having this same problem and `ViewBag` doesn't work either. In fact, `@model <type>` and any `Html.*For()` methods don't resolve either. For instance, I get `"System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'HiddenFor' ..."` Any ideas?